# Magnitude of Fourier coefficients when $||f||_2 \leq 1$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L_2[- \pi, \pi] $  so that $||f||_2 \leq 1$. Can I say anything about $f$'s Fourier coefficients' magnitude without assuming anything else about $f$?

To be more accurate: The squared norm of $f$'s Fourier series expansion of order $N$ satisfies:

$$||S_Nf||_2^{2}=\sum_{k=-N}^{N}|\hat{f}(k)|^2 $$

Is true that $||S_Nf||_2 \leq 1$ for all $N \geq 0$?

For example, when $f \in L_{\infty}[- \pi, \pi] $ and $||f||_{\infty} \leq 1$ it does not necessarily means that $||S_Nf||_\infty \leq 1 $. Take $f$ to be a squared wave - because of the Gibbs phenomenon we have peaks $>1$. However I cannot find a counter example when $p=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsevals's identity gives $\|f\|_2^2 = \sum_k |\hat{f_k}|^2$. (Using $\hat{f_k} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-ikt} f(t) dt$.)

Then if $\|f\|_2 \le 1$, this gives$\sum_k |\hat{f_k}|^2 \le 1$.